# Java: Server response is cut when stored into a string?

Tags: java, stream, http-headers

very strange problem, don't have any idea. Maybe you can help again - as so often :)

I create a simple UrlConnection and use the post-method. When I look into wireshark, everything is send right to me. I try to store the response into a string. And that string is a short version of the entire packet while it is closed right (with a /html-tag).

A diff in notepad gives me like this:

```
<a href="wato.py?mode=..."></a>
```

and in wireshark:

```
<a href="wato.py?mode=edithost&amp;host=ColorPrinter ... muchmuchmore ...
```

This is the place where it seems to get its cut

Really strange stuff, now this is my code:

```
public void uploadCsv(File csvFile) throws CsvImportException, IOException {

    String sUrl = String.format(urlBaseWato, hostAddress);

    String csvFileContent = readFile(csvFile);

    ParamContainer params = new ParamContainer().addParam("a", "a")
                                                .addParam("b", b)
                                                .addParam("c", "c");

    URLConnection connection = new URL(sUrl).openConnection();

    postData(connection, params);
    String resp = getResponse(connection); // <---- broken string here :(
    ...
}
```

-

```
private void postData(URLConnection con, ParamContainer params) throws IOException {

    int cLen = params.getEncodedParamString().getBytes().length;

    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches (false);

    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", authCookie.toString());
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(cLen));       

    //Send request

    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream (con.getOutputStream());

    os.writeBytes(params.getEncodedParamString());
    os.flush ();
    os.close ();

}
```

-

```
private String getResponse(URLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    connection.connect();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    String response = "";

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)        
        response +=line;

    in.close();

    return response;
}
```

Mysterious, I don't have the slightest idea. Can you help me?

Comment: IOUtils works without the broken string. Wondering why, since this is a simple implementation of getting a response without additional libraries. In all other cases it works. Just create an answer, then I'll vote it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does using [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) help?

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(sUrl).openConnection();
IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

or even:

```
IOUtils.toString(new URL(sUrl), "UTF-8");
```

Even if not, always consider it first to reduce the amount of boilerplate in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should make this an answer in case it's the problem and can get accepted.  I've seen cases where closing the socket cuts off the stream that's already been written there.  Try putting a Thread.sleep(5000) just in front of the socket closure.

Comment: Did you try this, or find another answer?